# MVC 5 + ASP Identity authorization - sharing cookie in subdomains

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, subdomain, asp.net-identity

I have local website with subdomains like:

```
localhost:55307
aaa.localhost:55307
bbb.localhost:55307
```

It works perfectly except authorization - if I log in in `localhost:55307` I'm not logged in `aaa.localhost:55307` because my subdomains are treated as separate domain. I looking for solution but I can't find any for Asp Identity (Form authentication in MVC 4 it's useless).
Based on some questions and answers in SO I did:

1. Edit `CookieAuthenticationOptions` class in `Startup.Auth.cs` as below:

   ```
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   CookieDomain = ".localhost",
   ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,12,0,0,0),
   Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
   {
       // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
       // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
       OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
   }
   ```
2. Get MachineKey from IIS Manager and add to web.config:

`<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <machineKey validationKey="61D42DE996486DEA64CEA26C0373C547E0D07108789662C2D2E15210A65C475925055009D962FEB3D5D93E9BEA3E3717187F1BCBF63E386EB198F641E6157044" decryptionKey="06CF7C1C31BDBD4E7056D0F3531BE253E98A658B50974155" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
  </system.web>`

Now i can login but cookies aren't shared - I still logged in one subdomain.

PS. I now that there is a lot of similar questions in StackOberflow but no one of them is about MVC 5 and ASP Identity and no of them got solutions.

Comment: I've similar necessity. Beside the fact that the code now is slight different in the current version, I am not able to change the cookie name, and I can't find any resource about this.